# What camera techniques did Nick Brandt use on Lioness with Cubs Under Tree, Serengeti?

Tags: camera-settings, animals

Does anyone know what technique Nick Brandt used in *On This Earth, A Shadow Falls,* and *Across the Ravaged Land?* (the ["On This Earth" Trilogy](http://www.nickbrandt.com/category.cfm?nL=0&nS=0)).

I was curious how he captured ["Lioness with Cubs Under Tree, Serenegeti"](http://www.artnet.com/artists/nick-brandt/lioness-with-cubs-under-tree-serengeti-snPBjeuhuHdKjXbKtvZ-dg2).

To me, it looks photoshopped.

Comment: Can you describe what aspects of the image make you say it looks photoshopped?

Comment: @MikeW It's the way the Lioness look so sharp. Kinda like it wasn't originally there.

Comment: Photography is all about the light. In this case it looks like the lioness is in good light while everything else is in shadow.

Comment: @MarkRansom I can definitely agree with your statement. I am growing in my understanding that photography is seeing light in a unique way and representing it to the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia article on Nick Brandt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Brandt#Photography):

> In 2001, Brandt embarked upon his first photographic project: a trilogy of work to memorialize the vanishing natural grandeur of East Africa.
>
> His photography from 2001 to 2012 bore little relation to the colour documentary-style wildlife photography that is the norm. He photographed on medium-format black and white film without telephoto or zoom lenses. (He used a Pentax 67II with just two fixed lenses.) His work was mainly graphic portraits more akin to studio portraiture of human subjects from a much earlier era, as if these animals were already long dead...

That doesn't mean he didn't scan the film and do digital manipulation, but part of the look is from shooting 6x7 medium format.